# Finding current cursor position in Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution-explorer

The Solution Explorer in Visual Studio is a nice tool for getting an overview of the code. But I find it annoying that I have to manually expand the file and browse its contents. Even pressing the sync button will only highlight the current file, not showing where in the file the cursor is.

Is there an automatic way of navigating to the current position in the Solution Explorer?

What I am missing is an overview of the file I am currently editing, highlighting the current location, without having to manually navigate in another view. (This feature exists in Eclipse, and even DataFlex Studio.)

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

If you use productivity power tools ([link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)) you can view the classes within a file from the solution explorer

Comment: This feature is built into Visual Studio 2012, which the OP is using. Also, the question isn't about the ability to display the contents of a file in Solution Explorer; the question is about automatically selecting a specific type or member within those expanded contents according to the location of the caret within the active file (basically making Solution Explorer behave like the Type and Member Drop Down Bars at the top of the editor window).